# How to create new mysql db when I got only files from the old one (wordpress, XAMPP)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

I am using XAMMP and WordPress. 
My old computer has broken and I restored files of my site from /htdocs/**MySite** and database files from /mysql/data/**MySite**

In new comp and XAMMP I've added site files and it's OK but how to **install database** only from these files? Mention I haven't it exported - only that folder in data mysql.

Thanks for any advices and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You only need to copy the .frm files to new C:\xampp\mysql\data stop mysql and than start the mysql and it will start working hopefully.

Comment: Always be in your services

Comment: what is the .frm files, where i can find them?

Comment: .frm file are mysql database information file and all the data they have in it . If you are using xampp than go to this path C:\xampp\mysql\data\ and you can find there it is for security if you get trouble with your phpmyadmin than you can collect your database from here if you need anymore assitance i am here tell me

Comment: Thank You a lot.
You mean C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql?
Because I can't find in in xampp\mysql them :/

Comment: I copied all .frm files from old /mysql/data/mysql to new /mysql/data/mysql, and now I've got a "problem with connection to database". I checked wp-config and there's acutall login and password to new database. What Can i do next?

Comment: there might be a problem with your username and password check out

Answer (score 0):

well you have the files, but no mapping. I would create a new database (fresh install), create a new entry via the user interface, see how it appears in the database, and map your files along the same pattern.

Comment: you mean to add new database in phpmyadmin and what then?

Comment: Sorry I misread the type of files you have. Yes, just do a fresh install and then copy your files over the server's, might work